# PHP - Overwrite Json with another Json

Tags: php, json

How can i do something like this? Does someone know how to get content from another Json file and overwrite another json file with new value. I tried this but no result. Can someone help me with this, i need this its an commission from school.

the two Json files are **list.json** and **listbackup.json**. I want a code that can use **listbackup.json** file to overwrite **list.json**.

```
 $backupFile= file_get_contents("listbackup.json");
        $backupFile= json_encode($backupFile, "\n");
        file_put_contents('list.json', $backupFile);
```

Comment: just remove the middle line ? reading a file does not decode the json, so no need to encode it again.

Comment: I wonder what your _real_ question here is... Obviously you can write something into a file. It is irrelevant what type of data that is to write data. So what happened that made you ask this question?

Comment: I have two files, one i want to use as backup and one i use to do changes and all that kind of stuff. Soo what i ask is if after the changes are made and saved in the list.json, how can i use the other list to fill this list back to normal as a backup list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the file is already `json` you dont need to use `json_encode`.

Make a backup

```
$listFile = file_get_contents("list.json");
file_put_contents('listbackup.json', $listFile);
```

Restore a backup

```
$backupFile = file_get_contents("listbackup.json");
file_put_contents('list.json', $backupFile);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$backupFile = file_get_contents("listbackup.json");
$backUpJsonDecoded = json_decode( $backupFile );

// do changes
$backupJsonDecoded->option->value = 'different';

$newFileContents = json_encode( $backupJsonDecoded );
file_put_contents( 'list.json, $newFileContents );
```